# Sharing Video to facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook

i need to integrate facebook api in to my application , i am new one to integrating api in android. Anyone help me out ,how to integrate the facebook api into  android application.

My intended to share the youtube video to facebook, i have the link , i need to share it to facebook  ,i don`t want to be post the link on my wall, i need to share the Video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This question was made long ago, but in case if someone else needs this like I did, here's the answer.

I won't post the entire code because it's too much. Just follow this page, is basically *copy-paste*: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Here's the important part, which is when building the params. Basically if you set just the `link param` in the `Bundle`, Facebook will automatically fill the rest of the info with the details of that video.

Here's an example:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
//params.putString("name", "Youtube Video");
//params.putString("caption", "YOUTUBE.COM");
//params.putString("description", "This is automatically set");
params.putString("link", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNfnLD6FiX0");
//params.putString("picture", "some-url.png");
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides an [Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk), read the README and look at the samples. It's easy to use.